# Pinia State update

Tags: vuejs3, pinia

have problems with pinia state update in vue 3 i need to recieve an array of objects - "list" and have action in pinia store:

```
    state: () => ({
            photoList: null,
        }),
    actions: {
        async getList({ abonId }) {
                const list = await api(API_METHOD.POST, {endpoint:`/api/list`, body: { abonId } });
                this.list = list; 
            },
     }
```

but when call getList() action in some children component state field list in parent component doesnt updates and component do not rerender;

```
const abonentRegStore = useAbonentRegStore();
const { list } = storeToRefs(abonentRegStore);
```

but if i use

```
this.list = null
this.list = list;
```

or

```
this.list.push(some value);
```

in action instead just this.list = list;  it updates properly

what am i doing wrong? how can i update store correctly?

Comment: If I were you, I would avoid destruction in Vue 3 & Composition. It breaks the reactivity system. Instead of `const { list } = storeToRefs(abonentRegStore)`, use the state directly in your code. `abonentRegStore.list ...`

Answer (score 0):

you have to define 'list' inside the `state` like so:

```
state: () => ({
       photoList: null,
       list: null
}),
```

it works for me everytime..

Comment: basically just keeping its reactivity concept.. here https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html#how-reactivity-works-in-vue